# Fórmula para rellenar las celdas en blanco en una columna de una hoja de cálculo de Google

Tags: array, revisión-de-código, google-hoja-de-cálculo, formulas

Tengo datos en una columna de una hoja de cálculo de Google con celdas en blanco entre ellos. Deseo que esos espacios en blanco se rellenen automáticamente.

En la siguiente tabla, en la columna A se muestran los datos de entrada y en la columna B el resultado esperado.

```
+----+---+---+
|    | A | B |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | a | a |
|  2 |   | a |
|  3 |   | a |
|  4 | b | b |
|  5 |   | b |
|  6 | c | c |
|  7 |   | c |
|  8 | d | d |
|  9 |   | d |
| 10 |   | d |
+----+---+---+
```

En Excel usaba en la primer celda en blanco, en este caso A2, colocaba una fórmula como la siguiente `=A1`. Luego la copiaba, seleccionaba el rango, y el comando seleccionar las celdas vacías y pegar. La hoja de cálculo de Google no tiene este comando incluído "de fábrica".

Tengo la siguiente fórmula de matriz pero implica ajustar la referencias para cada caso.

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(ROW(1:10),{IF(LEN(A1:A10)>0,ROW(1:10),""),A1:A10},2))
```

¿Hay una fórmula de matriz con un mínimo de parámetros que se tengan que ajustar a cada caso?

Atribución
La fórmula fue publicada previamente por mí como [respuesta](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88400/88163) a  [An arrayformula to find the previous non-empty cell in another column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/88394/88163).

Posteriormente esta fue referida en [An arrayformula to find the previous non-empty cell in another column and find the last row to work with](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90469/88163) por EumirAMC lo cual, junto con mi experiencia personal inspiró esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fórmula sin comentarios para "copiar y pegar"

```
=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(vlookup(ROW(A:A),{IF(LEN(A:A)>0,ROW(A:A),""),A:A},2),10,1))
```

## Explicación

La explicación se incluye como "comentario de código". La fórmula que se puede "copiar y pegar" se encuentra al inicio. Al final se incluye una variante.

### Fórmula simple

```
=ArrayFormula(                           // Fórmula de matriz.
   ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(                      // Limitar el tamaño del resultado final.
     VLOOKUP(                            // Buscar vertical. Devolverá una matriz. En una
                                         // fórmula de matriz funciona como un bucle.
       ROW(A:A),                         // Indica que se debe buscar todas las filas. 
                                         // Al no especificar una fila final el límite
                                         // se establece con ARRAY_CONSTRAIN.
                                         // por su número de fila.
       {IF(LEN(A:A)>0,ROW(A:A),""),A:A}, // Devuelve una matriz de dos columnas. La 
                                         // primera indica el número de fila de las  
                                         // filas con un valor y vacío en la celdas sin 
                                         // valor y la segunda es una "copia" de 
                                         // la columna A.
       2                                 // Indica la columna de la cual obtener el valor.
    ),                                   
    10,                                  // Indica el número de filas que se desea obtener.
                                         // Es el límite del bucle.
                                         // Este sería el único valor editar manualmente. 
    1
  )                                      // Indica el número de columnas que se desea 
                                         // obtener.
)
```

### Variante

En lugar de indicar el número de filas como un valor fijo, en inglés dirían "harcoded", se indica la referencia a la celda A10. En caso de requerir más filas, insertar las que sean necesarias entre la última celda con un valor y la celda A10.

```
=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(vlookup(ROW(A:A),{IF(LEN(A:A)>0,ROW(A:A),""),A:A},2),A10,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tengo una manera sencilla de implementar lo que pides. Desde el editor de código de la hoja pegale este código:

```
function AutoFill(values)
{
  var last = "";

  for(var i = 0 ; i < values.length ; ++i)
  {
     if(values[i] == "")
       values[i] = last;
     else
       last = values[i];
  }

  return values;
}
```

Y desde la hoja hazle en la casilla B1 = AutoFill(A1:A10)

Si te da algún problema, dilo.

Como antes, me ha parecido interesante la pregunta y he hecho otro post en mi blog: http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/como-autorellenar-campos-de-un.html

Si, ahora hay link a la pregunta y al perfil de quien lo pregunta :D

Nos vemos

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta correcta si hay alguna que te haya servido

Comment: Acepté la otra respuesta pues la pregunta es sobre una formula, que si bien una función personalizada es una forma de hacerlo, la otra respuesta me parece mejor pues no requiere crear un script y por ende es mas sencilla de implementar/adoptar.

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias. Esta solución también me ha ayudado a mi.

Estaba tratando de usar esa formula en un script de google de la siguiente manera:

```
cell.setFormula("=ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(vlookup(ROW(B:B),{IF(LEN(B:B)>0,ROW(B:B),""),B:B},2),3,1))");
```

Pero me arroja:

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 5, file "Test")

Creo, no estoy seguro que error me aparece por las comillas? Algo así sucedía en VB pero lo solucionaba con más comillas.

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: La zona de respuestas no es espacio para exponer dudas o comentarios, si requieres ayuda lee [ask] y por favor abre una nueva pregunta